# Globe rotate animation in android

Tags: android, google-maps, webgl-earth

Guysss currently I am using

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                    latLng).zoom(16).build();

            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

But I need globe rotate animation. In such a way that when user open's app a marker float around globe having in sync with zoom and land at user's current location.

My major concern is how to show 3d globe like google earth in android.

I have listened about webglearth. But there is no api of webglearth available for android. Please suggest me some way to overcome this problem.

Comment: you can't use google maps api. That's 2D only. Try exploring worldwind (there's also a webgl version) or search for "3D globe" softwares

Comment: Webgl works on html5 but I need some native solutions.